# How to think about that $A \subset B \iff B^\perp \subset A^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $span(A) \subset span (B)$, A and B are matrix.  Then it is equivalent to saying $span(B)^\perp \subset span(A)^\perp$. How to think about this relationship?

My idea is to say we are in a 4-dimensional space. Say A is 1-dimensional and B is 2-dimensional space. Then $A^\perp$ is 3-dim and $B^\perp$ is 2-dim space. Thus, $B^\perp \subset A^\perp$. Is my idea correct?

Comment: I tend to think these things as complements

Comment: Your $A$ and $B$ should be sets (of vectors) in a vector space. Saying $A$ and $B$ are matrices, then saying they are one dimensional etc. are incorrect statements that can mislead your understanding.

Comment: Also, the dimension argument is not precise and incomplete without added information. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, we can have span of ${e_1,e_2}$ which is 2 dimensional and span of ${e_3}$ which is one dimensional, but the latter is not contained in the former.